# Combinations of up to eleven letters

Tags: combinatorics

How many combinations of all sizes can be formed with the first 11 letters of the alphabet, a; b; c; d; e; f; g; h; i; j; k ?

If for example abc is a solution then bac is not an additional solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Combinations or permutations ?

Comment: permutations, sorry

Comment: @fosho "abc" and "bac" are different permutations, so will constitute 2 different solutions, yet you say that it's not an additional solution. This is why Amr asked if you wanted combinations.

Comment: Sorry its late here...combinations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each letter $a$ through $k$ can either be included in the word or not included in the word, so that's two possibilities for each of the $11$ letters, for a total of $$\underbrace{2\times 2 \times \cdots \times 2}_{11 \text{ times}} = 2^{11}$$ possible words, assuming you count the "empty word" with $0$ letters.

Answer (score 2):

If we think of possible combinations of the first eleven letters of the alphabet as subsets, then the number of combinations of your letters can be equated to the size of the **[powerset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set)** $\mathcal{P}(S)$ of $S =\{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h,i, j, k\}$.
That is, the number of possible combinations of the letters in $S$ is equal to *the number of subsets of set* $\,S\,$, (*including* the empty set). The size of the powerset $S$ equals $2^{|S|}$, where $|S|$ denotes the size, or cardinality, of set $S$.

Since $S$ has 11 elements, $|S| = 11$, so the number of subsets of $S$ is equal to $2^{11}$. If we *exclude the empty set* - which is a subset of every set (and here would represent "the combination of $0$ letters"), then we have $2^{11} - 1$ possible combinations (of all sizes $\ge 1, \le 11$) of the letters of $S$.

---

Put differently: We can compute

(# ways to choose 11 letters) + (# of ways to choose 10 letters) + ... + (# of ways to choose 2 letters) + (# of ways to choose 1 letter) =
$$\binom{11}{11} + \binom{11}{10} +  \cdots +\binom{11}{2} + \binom{11}{1} = 2^{11} - 1 = 2048 - 1 = 2047\;\;$$ possible combinations (assuming a "combination" has at least one letter, and no more than $11$.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow a combination of size zero then $$\sum_{i=0}^{11} {11 \choose i} = 2^{11} = 2048$$ but if not then one less, i.e. $2047$.

Answer (score 1):

This is the numbr of subsets of $\{a,b,...,k\}$ is $2^{11}$

If you don't allow the empty combinations is $2^{11}-1$